# how to images uploaded multiple users in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

[image]
[image]

> this is my screen shot,see user1 uploaded some files/images for example (image1,image2 and image3).Another user(user2) uploaded some files/images (image4,image5,image6).Both user uploading files/images at same time.I'm using single directory for users files uploaded directory.Now I'm facing which files/images which user uploaded it?this angular.js file

```
'use strict';
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#drop_div',function(){
            $('#file_upload').click();
        });
    });
    angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload']).controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
       var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({url: 'upload.php'});
       console.log('uploader---------'+uploader);
        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'customFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                    var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
                    var file_exten_val = '|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|gif|application|x-zip-compressed|'.indexOf(type);
                    var file_name = item.name;
                    var slice_exten = file_name.split('.');
                    console.log([type,file_exten_val]);
                    if((file_exten_val == -1) && (slice_exten[1] =='epub') || (type =='x-zip-compressed')){
                        return this.queue.length < 20;
                    }else if(file_exten_val >= 0){
                        return this.queue.length < 20;
                    }          
           }
        });
    }]);
```

> upload.php

```
<?php 
    if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
        
        $tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
        echo $uploadPath;
        move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $uploadPath );

        $answer = array( 'answer' => 'File transfer completed' );
        $json = json_encode( $answer );

        echo $json;

    } else {

        echo 'No files';

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You could add a user's unique id to the name of the file? Or store each users images in their own sub-directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API), you can send some form data with your files (param **formData**):

```
'use strict';
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#drop_div',function(){
            $('#file_upload').click();
        });
    });
    angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload']).controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
       var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({url: 'upload.php', formData: [{username: 'MyUsername'}]});
       //[...]
    }
```